# Excel SUMIFs with IF, OR, and AND

Tags: excel, if-statement, sumifs

Below is a link to the data I am working with: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iYdfVBKoX433cycJGbvtQ6hAfbD3jxkkxRTMTKuUG9o/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to make a single function which will sum the accomplishment points of a single day with a range of different acronyms. This means I need a function that looks something like this:

```
SUMIFS(Accomplishment points, range-of-acronyms,OR( Acronym="SNE",Acronym="SCE",  Acronym = " ", Acryonym = "TSD"), range-of-being, Begin-date=desired-date, range-of-end-date, enddate=desired date)
```

I know you can't us OR, but SUMIFS(SUMIFS()) doesn't work in this case either. I also have tried using ideas like SUMIFS(INDEX(METHOD) but that didnt seem to work either.

I appreciate your help in advance. I have looked around for people doing similar things but have been unable to find a solution that works with how many OR statements I need.

Comment: using your pseudo code `=SUMPRODUCT((Accomplishment points)*((range-of-acronyms="SNE")+(range-of-acronyms="SCE")+( range-of-acronyms= " ")+ (range-of-acronyms = "TSD"))*(range-of-being<=desired-date)*(range-of-end-date>=desired date))`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SUMIFS for each of the acronyms and then add them together.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Accomplishment points, range-of-acronyms,"SNE", range-of-being, Begin-date=desired-date, range-of-end-date, enddate=desired date),SUMIFS(Accomplishment points, range-of-acronyms,"SCE", range-of-being, Begin-date=desired-date, range-of-end-date, enddate=desired date), etc.)
```